# ftp> how to recursively search and change mode?

Tags: command-line, permissions, ftp, chmod

Sorry if that was a repeated question! all my search results leads to 'SSH' results...

I'm asking about **FTP**, How can I recursively change mode from FTP using the terminal?

Again: I'm using **FTP**, not SSH or SFTP, so, I guess these are the only option which I have:

```
ftp> ?
Commands may be abbreviated.  Commands are:

!           dir         mdelete     qc          site
$           disconnect  mdir         sendport    size
account     exit        mget        put         status
append      form        mkdir       pwd         struct
ascii       get         mls         quit        system
bell        glob        mode        quote       sunique
binary      hash        modtime     recv        tenex
bye         help        mput        reget       tick
case        idle        newer       rstatus     trace
cd          image       nmap        rhelp       type
cdup        ipany       nlist       rename      user
chmod       ipv4        ntrans      reset       umask
close       ipv6        open        restart     verbose
cr          lcd         prompt      rmdir       ?
delete      ls          passive     runique
debug       macdef      proxy       send
```

I don't have `find`, so when I tried:

```
ftp> find
```

I got:

```
?Invalid command
```

When tried:

```
ftp> chmod 755 $(find /path/to/dir -type d)
```

Got:

```
550 Could not change perms on $(find: No such file or directory
```

And I didn't get enough info from `help` when I tried:

```
ftp> help chmod
```

It gives me only:

```
chmod       change file permissions of remote file
```

So, how can I **recursively** do a search for folders/files only to `chmod` them?

Something like:

```
chmod 755 $(find /path/to/base/dir -type d)

chmod 644 $(find /path/to/base/dir -type f)
```

But from **FTP** ?

Answer (score 3):

This would be much easier with a proper shell.

A [*standard* FTP server](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#page-32) won't let you chmod at all. All `SITE` commands, `SITE CHMOD` included, are non-standard extensions. So your FTP server might support recursion. It probably doesn't. You'll only find out by figuring out what server it is you're connecting to and then reading its documentation.

However as a workaround, you could just use a client that allowed you to select multiple files and perform batch operations on them. It isn't recursion but it's *like* recursion.

I'm thinking clients like Filezilla. Select all your files, right click them and go to properties and change all their permissions at once.